# How would you say it if you can pay something in separate parts?

Tags: word-request

Let's say you have to pay an amount, and you can pay it in separate parts, what's the word to describe that? I'm sure there's a right word for this but I just can't put my fingers on it.

Comment: Are you making most of the payments before receiving the product, or after receiving the product?

Comment: If you pay for some of it in cash and the rest with credit, then you are making *partial payments*. That's something different from the *instalments* mentioned in the answer. It depend on the exact scenario behind your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase is "pay in installments". ("instalments" in British English)

The definition is:

> a sum of money due as one of several equal payments for something, spread over an agreed period of time.
>
> <sup>*(from google)*</sup>

[Usage](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/instalment) of "installments" in sentences:

> We agreed to pay for the car by/in installments.

Alternatively, in British English, it can also be termed as "hire purchase".

> a system by which one pays for a thing in regular instalments while having the use of it.
>
> <sup>*(from google)*</sup>

Comment: According to [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/installment), "instalments" is the British spelling, and "installments" is the American spelling.

Comment: @AgentSquid You’re welcome, glad to be of help :)